# brief function code for null check in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a test function and return Int.

```
  fun test ():Int {

        colors?.let { colorsArrayList ->

            color1 = colorsArrayList.getOrNull(0)?.let {
                return if (HexColorValidator().validate(it)) {
                    Color.parseColor(it)
                } else {
                    Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
                }
            } ?: kotlin.run {
                return Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
            }

        } ?: run {
            return Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
        }

        return Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
    }
}
```

can I write a brief then now?

```
return Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
```

this very repeated. can brief this line code?

Comment: I think best approach would be to omit handling default color at each step, try to access element, validate it etc. and just as final step fallback to default color.
You can even make it in : 'return color ?: Color.parseColor("#..");

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I see code with a lot of conditional logic, I try to remember that I can "push" nulls rightward. Instead of handling if/else every time you need to test for null, imagine that you just take what you want (happy path) and pass the nulls on. Eventually, at the end, you'll end up with either the answer you want or null, and can return the value you want.

For example (mostly untested):

```
fun test() =
    colors
        ?.getOrNull(0)
        ?.let { if(HexColorValidator().validate(it)) Color.parseColor(it) else null }
        ?: Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
```

Another way to make this easier to read is to extend `String` (what I'm presuming you have in `colors`) to hide the call to `HexColorValidator`:

```
fun String.parseColor(): Int? =
    if (HexColorValidator().validate(this)) Color.parseColor(this)
    else null
```

And then your `test()` function gets a bit simpler:

```
fun test(): Int =
    colors
        ?.getOrNull(0)
        ?.parseColor()
        ?: Color.parseColor("#8DE7C1")
```

Comment: Good approach! The `if (a) b else null` can be further simplified to `b.takeIf { a }`

Comment: @TheOperator - True! However, you'd always be paying the price to call `parseColor()`, even if you didn't need it. I try to only use `takeIf` if I'm calling it on a value, rather than the result of a function. And in this case (validate then parse), you'd be doing it backwards (parse then validate), which might cause exceptions if `parseColor()` only accepts pre-validated input.

Comment: Also, I think the `?.let { it.parseColor() }` can be simplified to `?.parseColor()`.

Comment: Good catch @gidds, fixed! :) Thanks, I missed that!

Comment: Glad to help :-)  Kotlin's scoping functions (`let()`, `apply()`, `also()`…) are very powerful, but I find them a little less intuitive (even after using Kotlin full-time for more than a year), and have to stop and work out exactly what they mean.  I'm happy to use them when they're really the simplest way; but sometimes they're not…

Comment: I'm pretty used to them by now, sometimes that leads me to leaving them in when I shouldn't when I refactor (like how I did above!) :)

Comment: @Todd true, it's a bit strange that `takeIf` always evaluates the true-case, as opposed to a function with different parameter order:  `cond.ifOrNull { trueCase }` equivalent to `if (cond) trueCase else null`. If needed often, such an extension function could be defined.